# Alias for nested variadic templated struct in VC++2013

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

For a templated nested struct I can define aliases like the following:

```
template<typename T>struct Struct
{
    Struct(T value){}

    template<typename T1> struct Nested
    {
        Nested(T1 value){}
    };
};
template<typename T, typename T1>using NameT = struct Struct<T>::Nested<T1>;
using Name = NameT<int, double>; // Alias for a certain instance
```

Can someone please give me a hint how to declare an alias for the variadic one?

```
template<typename... T>struct Struct
{
    Struct(T... value){}

    template<typename T1> struct Nested
    {
        Nested(T1 value){}
    };
};
template<typename... T, typename T1>using NameT = struct Struct<T...>::Nested<T1>; // This seems ok
using Name = NameT<int, double>; // error C976: 'Name': too few template arguments
```

Comment: not sure if [this is what you want](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9yaeyJgzhrx0wwqT); if you compile using e.g. clang you will get much more descriptive error messages (e.g. `template parameter pack must be the last template parameter`)

Comment: @m.s. with your link (clang) and e.g. C++14 settings it tells me, that no matching constructor for initialization of 'Name' (aka 'Struct<double>::Nested<int>') can be found, but the parameters are wrong (it should be Struct<**int**>::Nested<**double**>), so I'm not sure if all compilers can deal with this code above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
template<typename T1, typename... T>using NameT = 
   typename Struct<T...>::template Nested<T1>; // This seems ok
   ^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^
using Name = NameT<int, double>;
```

Mind though that parameter pack must be at the end so the definition is slightly changed.

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b59bdaff3855ca88)

Comment: not really for VC++12: error C3860: template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list - any other suggestions?

Comment: Funny it works for me both in VC++13 and VC++15 and gcc and clang [test code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b59bdaff3855ca88).

Comment: Ahhh, it was the magic **<>::template** keyword missing in my code. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to :

```
template<typename... T>
struct Struct
{
    Struct(T... value){}

    template<typename T1>
    struct Nested
    {
        Nested(T1 value){}
    };
};

template<typename T1, typename... T>
using NameT = typename Struct<T...>::template Nested<T1>;
using Name = NameT<int, double>;

    int main()
    {    
        Name f(1);
    }
```

The variadic template has to be at the end of the template argument list.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename... T>
struct Struct
{
    Struct(T... value) {}

    template <typename T1>
    struct Nested
    {
        Nested(T1 value) {}
    };
};

template <typename, typename>
struct split;

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
struct split<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = typename Struct<typename std::tuple_element<Is, T>::type...>::template Nested<typename std::tuple_element<sizeof...(Is), T>::type>;
};

template <typename... T>
using NameT = typename split<std::tuple<T...>, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)-1>>::type;

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<NameT<int, double, char>
                             , Struct<int, double>::Nested<char>>{}, "!");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/053e800245fd7be0)

Comment: is this VC++2013 code? Cause I get the error C2039: 'index_sequence' : is not a member of 'std'